# Trying to show AM-GM mean inequality

Tags: inequality

I want to show that

$$ ( \prod_i^n x_i )^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n x_i $$.

I know there exists plenty of solutions to this problem. However, I know this result follows this directly by the following:

Suppose $x_1,... x_n \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} $ and $\alpha_1 + ... + \alpha_n = 1 $, $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0 }$ then

$$ x_1^{\alpha_1}...x_n^{\alpha_n} \leq \alpha_1x_1 + ... + \alpha_n x_n $$

Is this result true?

Comment: It is. It's generally called the weighted AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking logs, you want to show

$$\sum \alpha_i \log x_i \le \log \left( \sum \alpha_i x_i\right) $$

Hint: Jensen

Answer (score 1):

It is suffice to show for two variables, and you can how it by convex function inequality. In more detail, t
$$
e^{\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y} \leq \lambda e^{x} + (1-\lambda)e^{y}
$$

and set $\alpha_{1} = \lambda$, $\alpha_{2} = (1-\lambda)$, $x = \log x_{1}$, $y = \log x_{2}$